# Immer Produce not causing Redux to re-render. Modifying Draft AND Base State in Reducer

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, mutation, immer.js

I'm trying to implement immer produce, but it is not causing Redux to re-render. On the contrary, it's updating both newState and the base state. They are both equal in the console log. The commented out spread operator works. I want to use immer here and i'm pretty confused. Thanks!

```
case Types.UPDATE_GROUP: {

      // this works and causes re-render
      // return {
      //   ...state,
      //   selectedGroup: {
      //     ...state.selectedGroup,
      //     user: {
      //       ...state.selectedGroup.user,
      //       notification: action.payload.value,
      //     },
      //   },
      // };

      //returns false
      console.log(action.payload.value)

      // returns true
      console.log(state.selectedGroup.user.notification)

      //this equally modifies base state and newState and does not cause a re-render
      const newState = produce(state, (draft) => {
        draft.selectedGroup.user.notification = action.payload.value;
      });

      // returns false
      console.log(state.selectedGroup.user.notification)

      // returns true
      console.log(
        'newState === State',
        newState.selectedGroup.user.notification ===
          state.selectedGroup.user.notification
      );
      return newState;
```

Comment: Very weird.  Is there any chance that you are mutating `user.notification` in the component itself?  If you try logging `state.selectedGroup.user.notification` above the `const newState = ` is it already set to the same value as `action.payload.value`?

Comment: It's not the same value.